# Automatic log truncation when scripting from SQL 2008 to 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have to convert a sql server 2008 database to a sql server 2005 database. As far as I understand it, the only reliable way to do this is by scripting the database to an earlier server version. Now, my client has requested to 'get the database in the right format and with the transaction log truncated'. I have never worked with sql server 2005 and am fairly new to sql server 2008 as well, and I can't figure out if there is any way to ensure automatic transaction log truncation. As far as I can see, this concept doesn't exists as such in sql server 2008.

So my question is: Does anyone have any idea how to meet my clients request?

Answer (score 2):

I think what they're asking for is to set the database to Simple Recovery mode. That will empty the transaction log at each check point. But, make sure they understand that this means that recovery of the data to a point in time is not possible. You'll only ever be able to recover to the last full backup (or differentials if any). Log backups will not exist.